# $mdDialog ok/cancel with angular translation

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

1) The `$mdDialog` needs to be set in js, i cannot find a way to define the properties needed to create a dialog in HTML code. Since I need to translate the `ok` and `cancel` button I need to build the dialog (at least partial) in HTML (since translation are recommended to take place in the view). I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

2) The htmlContent needs to load a injected HTML page. _disclaimer.html, I thought I might be able to remove the buttons `(ok/cancel)` and set them in the disclaimer, I can't seem to figure out this one either.

I'd like to have a modal with translated ok/cancel buttons and an injected HTML page (_disclaimer.html). I dont mind to program ok/cancel buttons in the _disclaimer.html. Please point me in the right direction

```
        var showDisclaimer = function showDisclaimer()  {
            var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
                .title('Are you sure to delete the record?')
                .htmlContent('my html content')
                .ok('Yes')
                .cancel('No');
            $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
                $scope.status = 'Record deleted successfully!';
            }, function () {
                $scope.status = 'You decided to keep your record.';
            });
        };
```

Comment: what do you want ? your question is not clear

Comment: "Can anyone advice me on the best way to approach this issue", sorry for not being clear

Comment: what do you mean by _The $mdDialog needs to be set in js_

Comment: you want `Yes` and `No` from your translations ?

Comment: I'd like to have OK and Cancel in HTML so i can translate them.

Comment: @Micheal, check my answer and let me know if  you expected something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am assuming you've properly loaded `pascalprecht.translate` and added translations for whatever you want. (`OK/Cancel` in this case). Now you can translate them in your controller and model that value in your view. for example
 `controller.js`

```
 app.controller('TranslateMe', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, 
  $translate) {
  $translate('PAGE.OK')
    .then(function (translatedValue) {
        $scope.ok = translatedValue;
    });
$translate('PAGE.CANCEL')
    .then(function (translatedValue) {
        $scope.cancel = translatedValue;
    });
});
```

And same goes for anyother value you want. Values don't need to be in `html` for translations. You can even translate them in your `controller` as I've mentioned above. Now for translated text of `ok/cancel` you can do something like

```
var showDisclaimer = function showDisclaimer()  {
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('Are you sure to delete the record?')
            .htmlContent('my html content')
            .ok( $scope.ok)
            .cancel( $scope.cancel);
        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            $scope.status = 'Record deleted successfully!';
        }, function () {
            $scope.status = 'You decided to keep your record.';
        });
    };
```

Hope this will be helpful